# NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9813)

Tags: ios, webview, uiwebview, nsurlconnection

i want to load my Url in web view that shows me error like as `NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9813)`

Here i write my code like as

```
NSString *urlAddress = @"https://anyror.gujarat.gov.in/";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[self.revenueWeb loadRequest:requestObj];
```

I do googling for it and fine some solution like as add this code in `info.plist`

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
<key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
<true/>
```

then i added this code in my `info.plist` but it is not working.

Comment: See [these search results](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bios%5D+kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL+%27-9813%27+nsurlrequest). It seems to be related to certificates, not ATS.

Comment: This answer might help with your problem http://stackoverflow.com/a/20047835/1368032

Answer (score 1):

I can't view that site in Safari on OS X v10.9, either.  It gives a certificate warning.  Same with "openssl s_client".

Error 9813 is **errSSLNoRootCert**.  This indicates that the certificate chain cannot be validated back to a known anchor.  This usually means that the server is misconfigured, and is not providing a complete set the intermediate certificates between its cert and a trusted root cert.

See [Technote 2232](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2232/_index.html) for additional info.

Comment: This is helpful to know, but I don't think it really answers the original question.

Comment: I see your link to info on Charles Proxy in the simulator.  That could be the original poster's problem, but only if the original poster was trying to use an HTTPS proxy to debug a networking issue (which isn't indicated anywhere in the post).  Chances are, it was a misconfigured server, either with missing intermediate certs or signed by an untrusted root cert from an authority that iOS no longer trusts.