# Using self signed cert in Swift Playgroud

Tags: swift, ssl, swift-playground

We followed this [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20047835/47281) to have the Simulator trust self signed certificates.  Is there a similar approach to get a Swift playground to also trust the cert?

Comment: I don't know if there is such a way that allows the trust to be extended only to the playground, but you certainly could add the untrusted cert Keychain Access so that the cert is trusted by your whole user account though.

Comment: As far as I can tell the root CA cert is in my Keychain.  But that being said neither the Playground or Safari considers it valid.   To get the simulator to take it I have to configure in the simulator per link in description.   Maybe there is some other Keychain config I need to do to get this to work in playground and Safari.