# Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code 1202

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, ssl, nsurlsession, tls1.2

Hi I receive the following error:

> Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1202 \"The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “server-prod.name-cloud.com” which could put your confidential information at risk.\" UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://server-prod.name-cloud.com /v3/project/session/926B9E6BE31B/, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to connect to the server anyway?, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://server-prod.name-cloud.com /v3/project/session/926B9E6BE31B/, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9843, NSLocalizedDescription=The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “server-prod.name-cloud.com” which could put your confidential information at risk.}

I read all the [relevant docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2232/_index.html), we apply all the requirements in "Common Failures" section.

More details:

- the errors received only from Germany(except 4 times in the past 2W that was from Italy)
- It is not reproducible in house
- Eventually after tons of retries the uploads go throw
- This was received booth in iOS 10.x.x & 9.x.x
- I use amazon servers with [2016-08 SSL Security Policies](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-security-policy-table.html),
  so according to [apple](https://support.apple.com/en-il/HT206871) it should be OK

In the app I use:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
   <dict>
      <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
   <true/>
</dict>
```

note - in production I always use HTTP’s, I leave the NSAllowsArbitraryLoads because some testers offshore can switch the rout to HTTP for debugging.

Comment: You read it [(http://lithium3141.com/blog/2015/08/21/shipping-an-app-with-app-transport-security/](http://lithium3141.com/blog/2015/08/21/shipping-an-app-with-app-transport-security/)

Answer (score 44):

For the devs who are working with a server locally and need to get the iOS Simulator to trust the certificate. Follow the steps below:

1. Get the `.cer` file by exporting the certificate from the Keychain. You need the certificate file in a valid format and its easiest to get this by
   exporting it from the Keychain.
2. Drag and drop the aforementioned `.cer` file onto the simulator. It should give you a prompt on installing a "Profile". Go ahead and follow the instructions to install it.
3. For those who are working with the latest versions of Xcode and iOS Simulator. You need to do 1 last step. The Simulator must be explicitly told to trust the root CA. Do this by going to `General -> About -> Certificate Trust Settings -> "Enable Full Trust for Root Certificate" for your particular certificate`

Hopefully, this saves headaches for some people!

Comment: The "Enable Full Trust for Root Certificate" option is not present on my simulator running ios 10.3

Comment: In my case, the option to "Enable Full Trust for Root Certificate" appears only for root certificates. It does not appear for intermediate or leaf certificates.

Comment: I followed the steps above, but still getting the error. Does this solution work only for a server hosted on the same machine, as that of the simulator? Basically, for me, the server resides on another machine, but in the local network where I can access it by passing IP address. For some reasons, I cannot run an instance of the server on my machine.

Comment: Also come unstuck at step 3. :( (latest Xcode) .. I can't see my cert in the 'Certificate Trust Settings' list, only in General -> Profiles

Comment: It appears that on 12.2 (probably earlier versions as well) the procedure is now to go to general > profiles, select the cert, and hit install in the upper right

Comment: it worked for me, added proxy server's self signed certificate to simulator, installed it from settings and enabled full trust.

Comment: but what would happen in production?, and won't the App Review process reject it?

Comment: @AndyNadal, this is purely for working locally. It's bad practice to ask your end users to manually add unknown root CAs to a device to be able to use your production application.

Instead, what you would do is ensure your certificates are signed by an existing trusted CA

Answer (score 1):

If you're on a work laptop with any kind of security measures, the SSL certs may be getting inspected / MITM'd by the endpoint protection.

Try opening any web page in mobile Safari. I get these same `NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1202` errors there as I do for https API requests from Xcode in iOS Simulator.

Solution will be to turn off this security feature...

Or install a certificate:   https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1948/_index.html

Similar issue is asked here: [iOS Simulator not works on https, all https are evaluated as not trusted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47064807/ios-simulator-not-works-on-https-all-https-are-evaluated-as-not-trusted)

[image] [image]

Answer (score -3):

It took a lot of time for me to find a fix for this:

If any of us ran across the certificate issue,.
It is because of antivirus preventing iPhone simulator to browse any websites.I was able to fix this issue by the following steps:

1. uninstall or turn off Antivirus in Mac.
2. erase all content and settings of simulator.
3. restart mac.