# iOS Simulator not works on https, all https are evaluated as not trusted

Tags: ios, xcode, https, ssl-certificate, ios-simulator

The Simulator Version 10.0 (SimulatorApp-835.2.1),
the Xcode version is 9.1

Seems that all the **https** connections are evaluated as *not trasted*, it is affected after the upgrade of Xcode and simulator.

I'm sure that the https connection are with valid certificate also because the same https://support.apple.com get **Not trusted** problem inside the simulator.

With safari I get some details about "not trusted" site[image]

clicking on

> showDetails

and

> view the certificated

the result is the follow:
[image]

I already tried to:

- rest the simulator
- erase all content and settings
- delete the certificate from keychain
- delete both OCSP and CRL cache

without any result.

Comment: The certificate is issued by Avast. This means that Avast software (antivirus or firewall) performs SSL inspection (or MITM) and sends you untrusted certificate. Either, disable Avast software or install the certificate on simulated iOS

Comment: @Crypt32 Thanks, disabling the web protection the issue is resolved. But I don't understand the root cause, just because with previous versions of simulator the was no problems with certification

Comment: @PasqualeVitale, I was able to fix this same issue by just disabling the "Scan secure connections" option, which is part of the Web Shield and didn't have to disable the whole shield.

Comment: I will upvote these if there were answers. Thanks!

Comment: I installed Kaspersky antivirus and simulator stop working. I will have to uninstall it. any idea how to resolve it without uninstalling the antivirus